# Posts page listing pages as well

Tags: posts, get-posts

I have set my Posts to output on a specific page by selecting that page as the posts page in the settings->reading tab.  That page is outputting content using my index.php template like I wanted.  However It is listing both "Posts" and "Pages" in its content.  I haven't had this happen before.  What could cause it.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Not sure what code you are looking for.  I am not modifying the query.  It should be just outputing posts into the loop of my index.php template file

Comment: You set your posts to output on a specific page. That sounds like you're doing something 'custom' already. Have you looked into 'pre_get_posts' ? That way you can 'override' the query and only show posts (or pages).

Comment: @Beee no. I just went to the wordpress setting->reading and set it to static home page and set my posts to a page.  Its basic wordpress functionality

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?  Or one of the themes that WordPress comes with?  If it's custom, does the problem still happen if you change themes?

Comment: could be caused by your theme or any of your plugins; possibly one of them using a 'pre_get_posts' action to include pages into the main query...